# Use IntentService with PendingIntent to receive background location updates

Tags: java, android, ios, performance, android-studio

I searched a lot everywhere and I am using LocationListener to get location update but once application is removed from background, location update stops.

Then I used a service for location update (I clicked "Allow all the time"), and its working just perfect but the problem is it is draining battery very fast. If I select "Allow only when using app", and remove app from background, again it stops sending update even though my service is ON!.

Please can someone help me with IntentService with PendingIntent to receive background location update.

I need to finish a project before end of July, I already spend 4 days, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be polling for location updates that frequently if it's having that much of a noticeable effect on battery life. But in general I wouldn't recommend trying to poll for them on a service. On Android 10 onwards as you pointed out allows the user to restrict location updates to the app being in the foreground. In Android 11 the permission can be revoked with each use of the app. Meaning for a large amount of the user base this behaviour won't function in the background.

Anyway if you do need them despite the API changes, look into the difference between Coarse and Fine location permissions. Using Coarse over Fine will make a noticeable difference to your battery drain.

Comment: can you help me with PendingIntent as well?

Comment: I haven't down voted anything. That was someone else and it could be for any number of reasons. As for background location updates, Google have a good sample project that does a better of showing this then I can in a comment https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/432d3b72b8c058f220416958b444274ddd186abd/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent